# Loyalty points tracking via SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table containing transaction details of a loyalty program site which carries mainly 5 columns.
Below is the same:

| member_id | points | date_transaction | date_expiry | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 20 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-04-05 | credit |
| 001 | 30 | 2023-03-02 | 2022-06-10 | credit |
| 001 | -15 | 2023-04-01 | - | debit |

for each credit transaction, we have a transaction date (date of rewards credit) and an expiry date for the concerned reward points. Similarly for each debit transaction. we have a transaction date (date of debit) and NULL against date_expiry.

The rule of reward debit is based on first input, first out basis. Rewards can only be debited out of active (not expired) reward coupons.

I wish to create a table with total active points for all members on current date.

| member_id | total_active_points |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 35 |
| 002 | 10 |

I tried using a recursive approach but that didn't work out. I also tried creating two separate tables i.e. credit & debit rewards, and attempted a join like:

```
select *
credit_table join debit_table on
credit_table.member_id = debit_table.member_id
and debit_table.date_transaction >= credit_table.date_credit
and debit_table.date_transaction <= credit_table.date_expiry
```

but again, could not move ahead with this.

sample insert query--

```
create table point_txn (
  member_id varchar(10),
  txn_date  varchar(10),
  status    varchar(10),
  points    numeric,
  exp_date  varchar(10)
);

insert into point_txn values
('003','2020-05-01','credit',20,'2020-08-01'),
('003','2020-06-01','credit',100,'2020-07-01'),
('003','2020-05-03','debit',-15,null),
('003','2020-07-05','credit',50,'2023-04-01'),
('003','2020-07-04','debit',-5,null),
('003','2020-07-06','debit',-20,null),
('003','2020-08-01','credit',100,'2023-02-01'),
('003','2020-08-03','debit',-25,null),
('003','2020-11-01','debit',-15,null)
```

Please help.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm more interested in the approach to be used. I sorta have flexibility on what database to pickup.

Comment: shouldn't member 001 have only 15 active points?  the debit occurred long after the first credit expired

Comment: what if the debit is for more points than the earliest valid credit.  would a debit split over multiple credits?  that will be very difficult if not impossible to calculate in SQL

Comment: Assuming you can’t have transactions in the future, don’t you just sum credits that have not expired and deduct debits? If so, this seems relatively straightforward using a case statement

Comment: @Kurt for member 001, the debit of 15 pts occurred before the expiry date of first 20 reward points credited. Hence, 15 points were debited from the first reward coupon.

Comment: @Kurt Pertaining to your second doubt, the debit will only occur when there's enough points to be debited. The source data will be from an actual rewards site where you can't use rewards more than you have in your account. Hope this helps!

Comment: @NickW - Nope that's not the case here.

Comment: Hi - could you explain why not? What are you doing other than summing the credits that have not expired and deducting the debits? Presumably all debits are valid as this would need to be checked by the loyalty application prior to debit record being created - creating debit records that have no credit record(s) to be applied to would make no sense

Comment: Hey @NickW, thanks for your involvement here. Can you please share a qry to support your answer? Maybe I can flag out the anomaly there if any.

Comment: @Dr.Octopus I think your sample data has a problem because to me it looks like the debit occurred nearly a year after the first credit expired.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have the following dataset:

| MEMBER_ID | POINTS | DATE_TRANSACTION | DATE_EXPIRY | STATUS | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 15 | 2022-04-12 | 2023-04-11 | credit | current credit (include) |
| 001 | 30 | 2022-06-30 | 2023-06-29 | credit | current credit (include) |
| 001 | 15 | 2022-01-15 | 2023-01-14 | credit | expired credit (don't include) |
| 001 | 9 | 2023-02-17 |  | debit | current debit (include) |
| 001 | 19 | 2023-05-24 |  | debit | future debit (don't include) |

and we want the result as calculated for today (calculating for an arbitrary date should be a trivial change once the basic solution works), then this SQL:

```
SELECT
MEMBER_ID,
SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'credit' AND DATE_TRANSACTION <= CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_EXPIRY >= CURRENT_DATE() THEN POINTS
     WHEN STATUS = 'debit' AND DATE_TRANSACTION <= CURRENT_DATE() THEN (-1*POINTS)
     ELSE 0 END) AS POINTS_TOTAL
FROM LOYALTY_POINTS
GROUP BY MEMBER_ID
;
```

Gives this result:

| MEMBER | POINTS_TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 36 |

If this is not the behaviour you are expecting, can you provide sample data and the expected output that illustrates the use case(s) that my solution has missed?

Comment: Thanks for the effort! but when you're considering credits points that have not expired till current_date and debiting from them only it doesn't add up. In a real-life scenario, let's say a person received some points in 2020 and spent some out of them in the same year within its expiration (Dec '20). In 2023, he received 100 points again and hasn't used them yet. Hence, in reality, he has 100 points to spend but as per your logic in code, you'll take those 100 points active today and debit the points he used in 2020 giving an erroneous output.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this case:

| member_id | txn_date | status | points | exp_date | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2023-01-01 | credit | +20 | 2023-04-01 | 20 |
| 001 | 2023-02-01 | debit | -10 |  | 10 |
| 001 | 2023-03-01 | credit | +20 | 2023-06-01 | 30 |
| 001 | 2023-05-01 | debit | -10 |  | 10 |

We have a +20 credit followed by a -10 debit followed by a +20 credit.  Simple enough so far.  At that point member 001 has 30 points.  But then we get to the last transaction.  At that point in time the original credit has expired so they only have 20 points to draw from, therefore the balance would be 10.  The problem is calculating that in SQL.  We cannot simply sum the credits and debits that came before, we have to exclude any credits that have expired *and also any debits against expired credits.*

Is my understanding correct so far?

If so, then I think I found a way to do it by generating "fake" expiration dates for the debits:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8EoSt2oYenvW7SqrLwaN5z/0

```
with txn as (
  select *,
      max(exp_date) over (
        partition by member_id 
        order by txn_date
        rows unbounded preceding
      ) as derived_exp_date
  from point_txn 
  order by member_id, txn_date
)
select 
    t.member_id,
    sum(t.points)
from
    txn t
where
    t.derived_exp_date > '2023-02-24' -- today
group by
    t.member_id
```

Edit:  I have concerns about a debit that splits over an expired credit and a non-expired credit.  If that is possible then I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: Hey @Kurt, I've added a sample qry in the question per your table. Your code doesn't give the expected output for the sample shared. A lot of thanks for your involvement tho!